# Encountering an ORA-29106: Cannot import PKCS#12 wallet error

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, plsql

I'm attempting to use utl_http from within Oracle 12c to Post a block of JSON data to a graphql end point. The http request fails with an error message of ORA-29106: cannot import PKCS#12 Wallet.

We have the Oracle Wallet set up and the CA certificate for the endpoint imported into the wallet. Both the Wallet path and Wallet password are correct.

```sql
 utl_http.set_wallet('file:/u01/app/oracle/admin/DB11G/wallet','PWD'); 
  req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json');
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'x-api-key', 'xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

  utl_http.write_text(req, json_body);
  res := utl_http.get_response(req);
```

The url endpoint is correctly specified including the https:// prefix, and the path is precisely what the oracle DBAs gave me. When the stored procedure is called it fails with the aforementioned ORA-29106 error.